# How to directly access the display for drawing

Tags: c, drawing, real-time

**Context**

I've been programming mainly as a hobby for some time now, mostly in C# and Java. I made many application (Windows Forms or Java Forms) that required animated content. In Java I would use `Graphics.drawX()` and redraw in function of time. When the animations were happening frequently the resolution would diminish or the application would slow down. I never gave it thought until I played a video game on the same computer that had so much trouble rendering a simple Java app. How can my computer instantly render a complex moving environment but rush a displaying a home-made 2048 game? I figured it must be because either I am misusing the draw functions, either because those functions are not optized for real-time render.

**Question :**
*How can I directly access the display without having to go through preprogrammed functions?*

I realize this maybe hard in higher level languages so let's say in C on a Windows OS. (But I would appreciate any answer relating to any language and/or OS)

I know it's a really vague question but I can't seem to find the right words to Google it appropriatly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (or maybe I should say should never) try to access the graphics driver directly on Windows.  You used to have write directly to video memory to do graphics prior to Windows as DOS did not support graphics or display management and the stability of those programs were always a bit dicey. On Windows, it owns the screen and you have to work through it to access it.

The very concept of a Windows-based OS is that the OS owns the display and gives application access to a virtual display so that the OS can hide it or move it around.  In most cases this does not cause a speed problem; but, in certain cases like gaming you need more speed; so, DirectX allows you tor transfer some of those task to the graphics card to get you the speed you need.

For more info on DirectX, check out  [Microsoft's Graphics and Gaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663279(v=vs.85).aspx) Resources